# retrofit2 embedded list returning null on valid reponse

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a json request/response pair that I am trying to use in android with retrofit2. The request works OK and I get the response shown here, which I verified by adding logging to the project.

The first two fields come back to my callback OK, but that "result" array is always null.

Send:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "Player.GetActivePlayers", "id": 1}
```

get back:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"playerid":0,"playertype":"internal","type":"audio"}]}
```

I used the website jsonschema2pojo to generate the following POJO classes

```
package retroKodi;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("jsonrpc")
    @Expose
    private String jsonrpc;
    @SerializedName("playerGetActivePlayersResult")
    @Expose
    private List<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_Result> playerGetActivePlayersResult = null;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJsonrpc() {
        return jsonrpc;
    }

    public void setJsonrpc(String jsonrpc) {
        this.jsonrpc = jsonrpc;
    }

    public List<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_Result> getPlayerGetActivePlayersResult() {
        return playerGetActivePlayersResult;
    }

    public void setPlayerGetActivePlayersResult(List<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_Result> playerGetActivePlayersResult) {
        this.playerGetActivePlayersResult = playerGetActivePlayersResult;
    }

}
```

sublist

```
package retroKodi;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class player_GetActivePlayersReturn_Result {

    @SerializedName("playerid")
    @Expose
    private int playerid;
    @SerializedName("playertype")
    @Expose
    private String playertype;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;

    public int getPlayerid() {
        return playerid;
    }

    public void setPlayerid(int playerid) {
        this.playerid = playerid;
    }

    public String getPlayertype() {
        return playertype;
    }

    public void setPlayertype(String playertype) {
        this.playertype = playertype;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

Activity call

```
kodiRequest_nullParams thisRequest = new kodiRequest_nullParams("2.0", "Player.GetActivePlayers", 15);
        (ApiUtilKodi.sendPost().kodiPlayer_GetActivePlayers(thisRequest)).enqueue(new Callback<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root> call, Response<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root> response) {
                player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root thisResponse = response.body();
                String hi = "hi";
                //List<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root.playerGetActivePlayersResult> thisResultList = thisResponse.getPlayerGetActivePlayersResult();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("response", t.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        });
```

Inside the "thisResponse" field, the "playerGetActivePlayersResult" field shows null.

I was expecting it to show an array, or at least a pointer that I could then assign to a List.

What in the world am I missing???? None of the examples a I could find had a list as part of a response. They were all either simple, 1 level json schemas, or they assumed a list of simple schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class `player_GetActivePlayersReturn_root` change

```java
@SerializedName("playerGetActivePlayersResult")
@Expose
private List<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_Result> playerGetActivePlayersResult = null;
```

with

```java
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<player_GetActivePlayersReturn_Result> result = null;
```

Comment: Yes! Of course... I did a refactor and renamed the class. When I did that, the IDE must have changed the name in the annotation so that it no longer matched the results in the json. Lesson learned.